# How do you say 100,000,000,000,000,000,000 in word form?

Tags: american-english, reading-aloud

I was reading a book called “BOMB” and the number 100,000,000,000,000,000,000 and I wanted to know what this number is in word form (how you say the word).

Comment: So it may be a duplicate, but why does ColleenV not help us by pointing out where to find the duplicate?

Comment: @JeremyC look at the top of the page (immediately below the question's title, but above its body). The link to the dup question is there.

Comment: If I were reading such a passage to someone, I would not even bother trying to come up with the correct word. I would simply substitute something like *a very large number*.